# How to resolve The ConnectionString property has not been Initialized in ASP.NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

ASP.NET Core-7 Web API application, I am implementing Entity Framework. Then I have this code:

```
public partial class DefaultDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public DefaultDbContext(DbContextOptions<DefaultDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DefaultDbContext(DbContextOptions<DefaultDbContext> options,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=DefaultDbConnection");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(DefaultDbContext).Assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new MerchantConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserRoleConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityRoleClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserLoginConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserClaimConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationRoleConfigurations());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserTokenConfigurations());
    }
}
```

My appsettings.json is as shown below:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultDbConnection": "Server=141.32.54.131,62762;Database=MyDB;Min Pool Size=100;Max Pool Size=1000;User Id=username; Password=password; trustServerCertificate=true"
  },
```

**Extension:**

```
public static class ConnectionConfiguration
{
    public static void AddDbContextAndConfigurations(this IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DefaultDbContext>(options =>
        {
            string connStr;
            connStr = config.GetConnectionString("Name=DefaultDbConnection");
            options.UseSqlServer(connStr);
        });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextAndConfigurations(environment, configuration);
```

However, when I did:

update-database -verbose  in the Package Console Manager, I got this error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been Initialized

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you provide the code about how you register dbcontext in `program.cs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString("xx")` to get the value of `ConnectionStrings`, You just need to pass the key in

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "key": "value"
  }
```

instead of passing `Name=key`, So here in your Extension method, you need to modify the code like:

```
connStr = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultDbConnection")
```

Answer (score 1):

The string you are passing to the UseSqlServer is the missing the key `ConnectionStrings`

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultDbConnection"));
```

ref; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core

Comment: I already did that. See the updated code. But still not working